# Using ReflectionClass in CakePHP 4.0.4

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to integrate the Playfab PHP SDK into CakePHP 4.0.4,

but Cake doesn't like the following line (included in the SDK example):

```
$apiReflection = new ReflectionClass("PlayFab" . $PlayFabApi . "Api");
```

it outputs the following error:

> Class 'App\Controller\ReflectionClass' not found

As far as I know ReflectionClass is native class in PHP, so I understand CakePHP is using some kind of PHP subset that doesn't allow ReflectionClass, probably because this class allows reverse engineering and so on.

Is there anything else I am missing?
and most important, how can I make `new ReflectionClass()` constructor work without compromising the whole project security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual: if you want to instantiate a class from the **global** namespace, while your current code is in another namespace, you have to prefix the class name using a backslash. Try to use :

```
$apiReflection = new \ReflectionClass
```

Answer (score 3):

After some more research I've found the solution was as simple as including:

```
use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionException;
use ReflectionMethod;
```